# Can't control appendChild() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, append

I have a trouble while split page by Javascript. I want to move 17 p tags into one div tag.
So I have 34 p tags like this:

```
<p>1</p> <!-- Each p tag have the value is the number of the p tag -->
```

And then I have this Javascript code:

```
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  for(i=0;i<17;i++){
    div.appendChild(p[i]);
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
```

And the result I received is in the div tag, there are 17 p tags but the value of these p tag is odd number, which mean like this:

```
1

3

5

7

9

11

13

15

17

19

21

23

25

27

29

31

33
```

This is the demo: http://jsbin.com/eyivic

Meantime, I want the p tags in the div tag will look like this:

```
1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

11

12

13

14

15

16

17
```

So what is the problem? How can I fix it?
Thanks you so much!

Comment: Are they in that order as you have them at the down or the up code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make an `appendChild` on the div, it removes the element of your `p` array. This will make this "only odds" behaviour happens. Let's say that you have 4 p elements.

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

If you make an `appendChild` from `p[0]` it will move your p element as you expected, but now your list is like this:

```
2, 3, 4
```

You are now pointing to `p[1]`, that you were expecting that was the element 2, but it will be the element 3 instead.

To fix it you can always point to `p[0]` and it will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop should look like this:

```
for(i=0;i<p.length;i++){
    var newNode = p[i].cloneNode(true);
    div.appendChild(newNode);
  }
```

it is removed from your array when you do appendChild. Cloning will solve your problem.

@memosdp pointed out that you actually want to remove those p elements from the original parent node. In that case, when your loop is finished, just clear out the old parent node:

```
// your loop is before this
var node = p[0].parentNode;
while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
}
```

Comment: this is right but actually creates copies of the `p` elements. In the loop remove the old `p` elements. `p[i].parentNode.removeChild(p[i])` after the clone

Comment: If it is removed in a loop, then the old problem will come back, they will be removed from "p" array :)

Comment: Ohh yes ... you are right again ... wants only the first 17 to be removed

Comment: Oh! Thanks you! I don't know about the cloneNode HTML DOM. I will study it. Thanks you!